# Rewriting an Array keys after sorting it

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 8];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 4, 9, 10];
$arr3 = [1, 2, 5, 11, 12];
$arrs = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
arsort($arrs);
```

I have sorted the `$arrs` to change it to `$arr3, $arr2, $arr1`, My problem is that it kept its `Array Key` as it is, I want to rewrite these keys by its new order, so instead of

```
[2]$arr3 [1]$arr2 [0]$arr1
```

it becomes

```
[0]$arr3 [1]$arr2 [2]$arr1
```

I thought about `explode()`ing then `implode()`ing the array again But it didn't work because it is a `MDArray` like the following `$arrs = implode(explode($arrs));` after `arsort()`.

What is the best and shortest way to re`[write][make]` the array keys?

Comment: Why not simply use [rsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) then? It's the `a` part of [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) that's maintaining the original keys

Comment: @MarkBaker that would work if i will always have 3 arrays that will always be reversed, I look for somethign like key reset.

Comment: So if you needed alternative sorting than simply reversal, you shouldn't be using either `rsort()` or `arsort()`

Comment: @MarkBaker at the first step i order the values by its `count` then reset the keys, @mega6382 answer solved it for me now.

Comment: If you need to sort by count of values, then `usort()` with a `count()` callback

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I understand, But it becomes a problem when i use `array_search` function inside a `foreach` function sometimes if the keys values kept as it is.

Comment: `usort($arrs, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });` sorts by count of values and resets the keys..... `uasort($arrs, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });` sorts by count of values and retains the original keys.... where's the problem?

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh, Now i see what you meant, That solves the problem in early stages.

Comment: Use the correct sort function, and you don't have the problem at all, don't need to do any kludgy workround to reset keys after the sort

Comment: from reseting the values using `array_values()` to using `usort` function. which one do you think would be the optimal way in my case?

Comment: Use the correct sort in the first place.... one function, not two functions, that's only the overhead of one function call, not two function calls; the code is readable, short, concise; it does exactly what is necessary, no more, no less... KISS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply use `array_values`;

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 8];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 4, 9, 10];
$arr3 = [1, 2, 5, 11, 12];
$arrs = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
arsort($arrs);

$arrs  = array_values($arrs);
```

This will reset the keys based on the order.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `rsort` if you don't need to keep key

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 8];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 4, 9, 10];
$arr3 = [1, 2, 5, 11, 12];
$arrs = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
rsort($arrs);
print_r($arrs);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/8OvMb)

Comment: That would work If i just want to reverse the values, But i'm trying to order the array by the highest count array, then change the keys values to be as same as the new order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `rsort()` instead of `arsort()` because, the latter will preserve the indices when sorting, while the first will reorder the values regardless of the keys.

Comment: Yes, But the problem is that i want the keys to be changed and not oversee it.